# 又 inside 他觉得冷，出门前，又穿了一件大衣。

Tags: grammar

My apology for posting many questions in short time.

> 他觉得冷，出门前，又穿了一件大衣。

My translation : *He felt coldness and putted on a coat before going out(the house/building).*

I can't understand why 又 is used here. If I assume that if the boy/man went out the house with 2 coats, then I can understand why 又 is used here.

How actually should this 又 be interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, **又** means again, adding on. It can be a repeat of the former thing or just another part of an extra thing.

In this sentence, 他觉得冷，出门前，又穿了一件大衣, tells us that he actually already had some clothes, and now he added another coat, which may not exactly be the second coat.

Answer (score 2):

Here, 又 means "additional", "additionally", or "again".

他觉得冷，出门前，又穿了一件大衣。- He felt cold, before leaving home, he put on **one more** coat. (one more = additional)

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is more context, then it's not hard to understand:

她穿了一件冬天的套头衫，但是她还是觉得冷，所以她又穿了件大衣。
She put on a winter pullover, but she still felt cold, so she also put on a coat.

也和又的意思差不多。

People I asked would not like to use 也 instead of 又 here, but they are not really sure why. Language intuition.

Baidu has this for 也和又的区别：

> 又，表示的是同一个动作发出者，发出的相同的动作；也，表示的是，不同的动作发出者，发出的同一个动作

Comment: 也 wouldn’t really make sense here, since the person is putting on an _additional piece of the same type of garment_. Had it been a different type of garment, it would work better: 他虽然穿了一件套头衫，但还是觉得冷，所以也/又戴上了帽子.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my perspective. In this sentence, 又 might exist in order to emphasize the fact that the man puts on other clothes, or to make the sentence read fluently.(In Chinese conversation, the sentence might not be natural if 又 is removed)
Anyway, I think there's no need to translate 又 into English here, it can be seen as a particle which puts an emphasize and make the sentence easy to read.

Comment: I don’t think removing 又 makes the sentence unnatural; it just changes the context. Without it, the implication is that he wasn’t wearing a coat (e.g., it’s summer and he’s just wearing a t-shirt), but he felt cold, so he put one on before going out. With it, the implication is that he was already wearing something fairly warm, but he felt cold, so he put on an _extra_ item of clothing, a coat, before going out.

Answer (score 0):

又 introduces an extra effort here. What makes him go for that extra effort? It's because he felt cold.

又 here implies that he might have gone out without a coat originally, then he found it's cold outside before going out and decided to put on a coat.